# Filter NSFetchedResultsController to get only objects with some relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two entities, A and B, and the following relationships:

A -> B - To many

B -> A - To one

In other words: A can have zero or more B and B can have only one A.

I want to use NSFetchedResultsController to show my A entries in a table view, but i want to filter the results by A -> B relationship. 
To do so, i have a UISegmentedControl, if the user taps the first segment i want to show only the A entries that have at least one relationship with B, and if the second segment is tapped i want to show only the entries with no relationships with B.

I'm using CoreData's NSManagedObject, so my A object has a NSSet property with all B entries in a relationships with A.

This is how i'm instantiating my NSFetchedResultsController:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:"A" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:descriptorKey ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


    NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                              initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                              managedObjectContext:context
                                              sectionNameKeyPath:controllerKey
                                              cacheName:nil];

    NSError *error;
    BOOL success = [controller performFetch:&error];

    if (success) {
        return controller;
    }
```

This code get all A entries, how can i make that filter?

Comment: Your fetch request doesn't have a predicate. That's where you define the filters.

Comment: But how can i make a predicate to filter by relationships? I'm trying by verifying NSSet count, but with no success so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a predicate to your fetch request:

e.g.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"B.@count == 0"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

This will filter `A`s that don't have any related B objects.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I was setting the predicate wrong, i was doing [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"B.count == 0"] instead of [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"B.@count == 0"]. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

As @Abizern mentioned in comments, you need to add a `NSPredicate` to your `NSFetchedResultsController`.  The predicate would be something like:

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"b == %@", myVarReferenceToB]];
```

If you only have a unique identifier in B (lets call it `identifier`) instead of an object reference you could write it as:

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"b.identifier == %@", myVarReferenceToBIdentifier]];
```

This will produce your filter.

Every time the user changes the segmented control you will need to re-build the fetch or you will need to keep one `NSFetchedResultsController` around per segment.

Comment: If you are going to rebuild the fetch, and the NSFetchedResultsController uses a cache, remember call [deleteCacheWithName:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSFetchedResultsController/deleteCacheWithName:)